# How to make web component to redender specific elements upon property update

Tags: javascript, web-component, native-web-component

```js
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        // Props
        this._color = this.getAttribute("color");
        this._myArray = this.getAttribute("myArray");
        // data
        
        // Shadow DOM
        this._shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
        this.render();
    }
    template() {
        const template = document.createElement("template");
        template.innerHTML = `
            <style>
                :host {
                    display: block;
                }
                span {color: ${this.color}}
            </style>
            <p>Notice the console displays three renders: the original, when color changes to blue after 2 secs, and when the array gets values</p>
            <p>The color is: <span>${this.color}</span></p>
            <p>The array is: ${this.myArray}</p>
            
        `;
        return template;
    }
    get color() {
        return this._color;
    }
    set color(value) {
        this._color = value;
        this.render(); 
    }
    get myArray() {
        return this._myArray;
    }
    set myArray(value) {
        this._myArray = value;
        this.render();
    }

    render() {
        // Debug only
        const props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this).map(prop => {
            return this[prop] 
        })
        console.log('Parent render; ', JSON.stringify(props));
        // end debug
        this._shadowRoot.innerHTML = '';
        this._shadowRoot.appendChild(this.template().content.cloneNode(true));
    }
}

window.customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <script type="module" src="./src/my-element.js" type="module"></script>
    <!-- <script type="module" src="./src/child-element.js" type="module"></script> -->
</head>

<body>
    <p><span>Outside component</span> </p>
    <my-element color="green"></my-element>
    <script>
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.querySelector('my-element').color = 'blue';
            document.querySelector('my-element').myArray = [1, 2, 3];
        }, 2000);
    </script>
</body>
```

I have a native web component whose attributes and properties may change (using getters/setters). When they do, the whole component rerenders, including all children they may have.

I need to rerender only the elements in the template that are affected.

```js
import {ChildElement} from './child-element.js';
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        // Props
        this._color = this.getAttribute("color");
        this._myArray = this.getAttribute("myArray");
        // Shadow DOM
        this._shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
        this.render();
    }
    template() {
        const template = document.createElement("template");
        template.innerHTML = `
            <style>
                span {color: ${this.color}}
            </style>
            <p>The color is: <span>${this.color}</span></p>
            <p>The array is: ${this.myArray}</p>
            <child-element></child-element>
        `;
        return template;
    }
    get color() {
        return this._color;
    }
    set color(value) {
        this._color = value;
        this.render(); // It rerenders the whole component
    }
    get myArray() {
        return this._myArray;
    }
    set myArray(value) {
        this._myArray = value;
        this.render();
    }
    render() {
        this._shadowRoot.innerHTML = '';
        this._shadowRoot.appendChild(this.template().content.cloneNode(true));
    }
}

window.customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
window.customElements.define('child-element', ChildElement);
```

Because each setter calls `render()`, the whole component, including children unaffected by the updated property, rerenders.

Comment: Please add an executable StackOverflow Snippet to your post. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. See [How to add a StackOverflow snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: What determines whether an element in your render tree is affected by an attribute change?

Comment: If it contains a property that's changed. Especially for children components. In Vue or React (or Lit), children components don't rerender upon unrelated property updates. Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-6glqtd?file=src/App.vue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you go native you have to program all reactivity yourself.
(but you are **not** loading **any** dependencies)

Not complex, Your code can be simplified;

and you probably want to introduce `static get observedAttributes` and the `attributeChangedCallback` to automatically listen for **attribute** changes

```js
customElements.define('my-element', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super().attachShadow({ mode: "open" }).innerHTML = `
      <style id="STYLE"></style>
      <p>The color is: <span id="COLOR"/></p>
      <p>The array is: <span id="ARRAY"/></p>`;
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    // runs on the OPENING tag, attributes can be read
    this.color   = this.getAttribute("color");
    this.myArray = this.getAttribute("myArray"); // a STRING!!
  }
  get color() {
    return this._color;
  }
  set color(value) {
    this.setDOM("COLOR" , this._color = value );
    this.setDOM("STYLE" , `span { color: ${value} }`);
  }
  get myArray() {
    return this._myArray;
  }
  set myArray(value) {
    this.setDOM("ARRAY" , this._myArray = value );
  }
  setDOM(id,html){
    this.shadowRoot.getElementById(id).innerHTML = html;
  }
});
```

```html
<my-element color="green" myArray="[1,2,3]"></my-element>
<my-element color="red" myArray="['foo','bar']"></my-element>
```

Comment: Brilliant. I modified a bit `setDOM(id,html)` to allow the rerender of child elements which may have innerHTML not subject to change `this.shadowRoot.getElementById(id).innerHTML = html == undefined ? this._shadowRoot.getElementById(id).innerHTMLhtml : html;`

Comment: you are still **changing** DOM (to the same value) Just add an ``if (html) ....``

Comment: Right, if the child custom element has `static get observedAttributes` it will rerender on its own when attrs change.

Comment: yes, it will (on every attribute change) force the ``atributeChangedCallback`` to run. Note that it also triggers on first parsing ``<my-element attr="foo">`` so either check for ``oldValue !== newValue`` or use ``this.isConnected``

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a certain **level of abstraction**. You are trying to emulate the Vue/React way of doing things where whenever the props change, the `render()` function is repeatedly called. But in these frameworks, render function doesn't do any DOM manipulation. It is simply working on **Virtual DOM**. Virtual DOM is simply a tree of JS object and thus very fast. And, that's the abstraction we are talking about.

In your case, it is best if you rely on some abstraction like LitElement or Stencil, etc. - any web component creation framework. They would take care of handling such surgical updates. It also takes care of scheduling scenarios where multiple properties are changed in a single event loop but render is still called exactly once.

Having said that, if you want to do this by yourself, one important rule: Never read or write to DOM from the web component constructor function. Access to DOM is after the `connectedCallback` lifecycle event.

Here is the sample that you can try and expand:

```js
import { ChildElement } from './child-element.js';

class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this._shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
    this.attached = false;
  }

  connectedCallback() {

    // Check to ensure that initialization is done exactly once. 
    if (this.attached) {
      return;
    }

    // Props
    this._color = this.getAttribute("color");
    this._myArray = this.getAttribute("myArray");
    
    // Shadow DOM
    this.render();
    this.attached = true;
  }

  template() {
    const template = document.createElement("template");
    template.innerHTML = `
      <style>
        span {color: ${this.color}}
      </style>
      <p>The color is: <span id="span">${this.color}</span></p>
      <p>The array is: ${this.myArray}</p>
      <child-element></child-element>
    `;
    return template;
  }

  get color() {
    return this._color;
  }

  set color(value) {
    this._color = value;
    
    this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#span').textContent = this._color;
    this.shadowRoot.querySelector('style').textContent = `
      span { color: ${this._color}; }
    `;
  }

  get myArray() {
    return this._myArray;
  }
  set myArray(value) {
    this._myArray = value;

    this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#span').innerHTML = this._myArray;
  }
  
  render() {
    this._shadowRoot.innerHTML = '';
    this._shadowRoot.appendChild(this.template().content.cloneNode(true));
  }
}

window.customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
window.customElements.define('child-element', ChildElement);
```

The above example is a classical vanilla JS with imperative way of updating the DOM. As said earlier to have reactive way of updating the DOM, you should build your own abstraction or rely on library provided abstraction.